# Convert Char* to array of Char*

Tags: c, arrays, string, converters

I am trying to convert a `Char*` to a `Char**`.

e.g. `"echo Hello World"` would become `{"echo", "Hello", "World"}`

I know, that I can get the single words from a `Char*` with `strtok()`.

But I have problems initializing the `Char**` , as the `Char*` is of unknown size, and the single words are of unkown size as well.

Comment: I assume you mean a "char" not a "Char". The char** should be to an array of pointers, each of which points to one of the strings. In other words char** wordlist = malloc( sizeof( char* ) * iWordCount )

Comment: Hmm so i need to create a copy of the char* , to first count the words and then inserting them, do i?

Answer (score 0):

Your `char**` is just a pointer to the first `char *` (or, the beginning of array of char pointers). Allocation of `char*[]` (it's **not** the same as `char**`!!) might be a greater problem.
You should use `malloc` for this task. If you do not know the number of `char*`s in advance, you can just guess some size, fill it with `NULL`s and call `realloc` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can run on your string and search ' ' (Space character)  then each space you found you can get substring with the function `strncpy` to get the string between the current space index and the last space index. Each string that you create you can store on "dynamic" array (with malloc and realloc).
For the first substring your start index is 0, and at the end of the string you get the last substring between the last space index and the string length.

Answer (score 0):

The first result in a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=strtok) gives you an example that you could modify:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>        

int main ()
{
  // allocate 10 strings at a time
  int size = 10;
  int i = 0;
  char str[] ="echo Hello World";
  char** strings = malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
  char* temp;

  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  temp = strtok (str," ");
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    strings[i++] = temp;
    temp = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    if(i % size == 0)
        //allocate room for 10 more strings
        strings = realloc(strings, (i+size) * sizeof(char*));
  }

  int j;
  for(j = 0; j < i; j ++) 
  {
      printf ("%s\n",strings[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: strtok() is a reasonable recommendation, but should be accompanied by a warning that it modifies the original string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t word_count(const char *str){
    enum { out, in } status;
    size_t count = 0;
    status = out;
    while(*str){
        if(isspace(*str++)){
            status = out;
        } else if(status == out){
            status = in;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void){
    char original[] = "echo Hello World";
    size_t i, size = word_count(original);
    char *p, **words = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);

    for(i = 0, p = original;NULL!=(p=strtok(p, " \t\n")); p = NULL)
        words[i++] = p;
    //check print
    printf("{ ");
    for(i = 0;i<size;++i){
        printf("\"%s\"", words[i]);
        if(i < size - 1)
            printf(", ");
    }
    printf(" }\n");

    return 0;
}
```